# Xcode 8 hangs / becomes unresponsive when opening storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, storyboard

I know this is a repeated question and the solution to this issue is by deleting some view and creating it again. But how do we decide by re design which view the storyboard issue will go. At the start I deleted the tab bar view from my app and then storyboard worked fine for some more days. Now I have so many sub views and controllers I don't know which one will help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: upgrade to xcode 9.2 it is much faster

Comment: Its happen because of automatic refresh of IBDesignable. For this goto Storyboard -> Menu Editor -> Automatically Refresh View just uncheck it . It will work fine.

Comment: quit xcode and start again

Answer (score 0):

I was faced same issue.

Please do as follow might be work for you.

Just go to preference > General tab > Unchecked live issue tab

Same as below image:

[image]

After done above step storyboard is not refresh everytime.